# Can I push staging to live using managed wordpress hosting like Kinsta or Wp Engine while site is developed using trellis/bedrock?

Tags: wordpress, deployment, roots-sage, kinsta

I have successfully developed my first site using Trellis/Bedrock/Sage. I have deployed it to staging and live on Kinsta without having any trouble.

Some redirection problems occurs when I add my real domain on Kinsta e.g. example.kinsta.cloude to example.com. I contacted the support and they told me they fixed it by making changes to my .env file. After fixing issues it started to redirecting in never ending loop due to SSL issue. It is resolved when I added my SSL. Now keep in mind my situation and please guide me.

Now I am making changes to the site in dev and deploying it to staging for testing live and showing it to client. Once they approve changes I need to push it to live. I have two questions:

1- Should I use Kinsta’s default button “Push Staging to Live” for deploying it to live?

2- Should I use Ansible deploy for this purpose also what changes I need to make and where to make so that .env related issues will not rise again. Also will SSL be an issue if I deploy using Trellis/Bedrock?

Thanks in advance for your advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself if we use bedrock setup we can not use  Kinsta’s default button “Push Staging to Live” for deploying it to live. We must need to follow the way Ansible deploy for this purpose.